# PHP Fatal error during installation

Tags: php, yii, filesystem

I am trying to run craft inside a homestead box. The box boots and installs everything correctly, and when I navigate to http://localhost:8000/admin I see the install screen and can click through the prompts. However, after clicking through the final screen I always get "Install failed  Please check your logs for more info.".

Here are the details for my setup:

- Host OS: Windows 10 1809
- Vagrant version: 2.2.4
- Virtualbox version: 6.0.8
- Homestead version: 8.5.5 (vagrant box 8.0.0-alpha2)
- Guest OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2
- Guest PHP version: 7.3.5-1

phperrors.log has this to say:

```
[03-Jun-2019 19:56:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught yii\base\ErrorException: unlink(/home/vagrant/code/storage/runtime/mutex/a78d6a4ecc5877cd5617ca990a2be38b.lock): Text file busy in /home/vagrant/code/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/mutex/FileMutex.php:161
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/code/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/mutex/FileMutex.php(161): ::unlink()
#1 /home/vagrant/code/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/mutex/Mutex.php(88): yii\mutex\FileMutex->releaseLock()
#2 /home/vagrant/code/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/mutex/Mutex.php(57): yii\mutex\FileMutex->release()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/vagrant/code/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/mutex/FileMutex.php on line 161
```

I've googled this error message but didn't find anyone with the same problem. The referenced line of code ([FileMutex.php:161](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/91c96ff4525b498b6849abd986e9dcaad2883043/framework/mutex/FileMutex.php#L161)) offers the clue that it may be an issue with operating systems (a different file unlock/delete procedure is used on windows).

In the vagrant box, the permissions on that file are wide open and I can delete the file with no problem.

```
vagrant@craftycoffee:/vagrant/storage/runtime/mutex$ ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jun  3 02:39 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jun  3 02:35 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Jun  3 02:35 4f99fda3d17d57459c4105d023bcba69.lock
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Jun  3 02:35 52fa75c9044f6df80d2103fad929036e.lock
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Jun  3 19:56 a78d6a4ecc5877cd5617ca990a2be38b.lock
vagrant@craftycoffee:/vagrant/storage/runtime/mutex$ rm a78d6a4ecc5877cd5617ca990a2be38b.lock
vagrant@craftycoffee:/vagrant/storage/runtime/mutex$ ls
4f99fda3d17d57459c4105d023bcba69.lock  52fa75c9044f6df80d2103fad929036e.lock
```

My best guess is that there is some weird interaction between windows and ubuntu when vagrant mounts that folder. However, I use vagrant for several other projects (all with windows host and linux guest) and have never seen any problems like this. I'm a complete noob with homestead/craft/php so I'm not really sure where to go from here; Any guidance on troubleshooting is appreciated. If there is any more info I can provide please let me know.

EDIT: I tried using [SMB](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/smb.html) to do the file mounting (I believe NFS is the default?) and it worked. However, this isn't an optimal solution because I have to put in my username and password every time I boot the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this issue: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4355#issuecomment-498829513

reproduced here for completeness:

> A yii variable 'isWindows' is apparently the way to correct this issue, but I haven't been able to find any documentation describing where/how to set this.

From your Craft config/app.php file, you can use this to set the isWindows property of the FileMutex class to true.

```php
return [
    'components' => [
        'mutex' => function() {
            $config = craft\helpers\App::mutexConfig();
            $config['isWindows'] = true;
            return Craft::createObject($config);
        },
    ],
];
```